# Compartilhar artigo no Facebook - Popup / Janela em branco

Tags: facebook, widget

Da última semana para cá, ao tentar compartilhar qualquer conteúdo do meu blog para o Facebook, recebo uma popup ou página em branco dentro do domínio do Facebook.

### Exemplos:

- [Compartilhar artigo 1](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?src=bm&u=http%3A%2F%2Fa.accioly.7rtc.com%2F2013%2F09%2Fmooc-principios-de-programacao.html&t=MOOC+-+Princ%C3%ADpios+de+Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o+Funcional+em+Scala&v=3) ([desse](http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2013/09/mooc-principios-de-programacao.html) artigo)
- [Compartilhar artigo 2](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?src=bm&u=http%3A%2F%2Fa.accioly.7rtc.com%2F2012%2F12%2Fjar-hell-um-guia-pratico.html&t=JAR+Hell+-+Um+guia+pr%C3%A1tico&v=3) ([desse](http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2012/12/jar-hell-um-guia-pratico.html) artigo)

Antigamente esses mesmos links podiam ser compartilhados sem problema, exibiam título, descrição e uma imagem. Agora mesmo que eu cole o link manualmente no Facebook nada disso aparece.

### O que já tentei?

1. Gerar metadata [OGP](http://ogp.me/) para o blog e artigos (apesar de saber que antes funcionava sem isso):

   ```
   <meta content='http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2014/09/o-que-e-data-science-e-por-onde-comecar.html' property='og:url'/>
   <meta content='O que é Data Science? Por onde começar?' property='og:title'/>
   <meta content='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-VzI5h7nikLM/VCRssVQmQwI/AAAAAAAAJE0/QKf16G5iR9o/s1600/Data_Science_VD.png' property='og:image'/>
   <meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
   <meta content='Anthony Accioly' property='og:site_name'/>
   ```
2. Hospedar minhas imagens em outro lugar.
3. Trocar o [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) por outros mecanismos, incluindo o [botão de compartilhamento](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) oficial do Facebook. Todos eles apresentam o mesmo comportamento.

---

O [debugger do OGP](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=a.accioly.7rtc.com) me retorna um a mensagem `Failed to get composer template data.` Porém não me diz o que falhou.

Alguém sabe como faço o compartilhamento voltar a funcionar? Ao clicar em um link ele deveria exibir a janela de compartilhamento como nesse caso: [Compartilhar essa pergunta no Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?src=bm&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F43306%2F100&v=3).

### Referências:

1. [**Why is the Facebook Share Button Displaying Blank Popup Window?**](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=750394444993657) - Nesse caso o problema era com o servidor de imagens.
2. [**Facebook share button gives blank popup for website homepage**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767963/664577) - Não funcionava na URL sem extensão (no meu caso não funciona nem em URLs sem extensão nem URLs com extensão .html)
3. [**Share Facebook Popup Window Blank/Empty**](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/5398091-share-facebook-popup-window-blank-empty) - Fala do *scraper* do Facebook e aponta para o *debugger*, mas não me diz como contornar o problema.

Comment: A discussão nos comentários estava se estendendo demais e foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19900/discussion-on-question-by-anthony-accioly-compartilhar-artigo-no-facebook-popu).

Comment: @bfavaretto, escrevi uma resposta tentando resumir os passos nos comentários e minha "solução" (só para ter fechamento). Veja com o utluiz se o conteúdo é pertinente para o Stack Overflow (achei que não agradou / encorajou muito a galera a participar). Se não for material adequado para o Stack Overflow não tem problema, vai virar artigo do blog que consegui resgatar das trevas hehehe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema resolvido (que pena que a recompensa foi para o limbo).

Tudo aconteceu devido a [esse favicon](http://s0z0tg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pOvhcR2DWzPHr171Z6EU1__JIjRYOT-LnciCsvCgOkOB8CbKrERBqGv4-oWaQD9M6uCX8EHk0MMc-JBsWyZtW3Z2G0U51YLiH/favicon.ico?psid=1) hospedado no [Microsoft One Drive](https://onedrive.live.com/). A URL foi [bloqueada](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://s0z0tg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pOvhcR2DWzPHr171Z6EU1__JIjRYOT-LnciCsvCgOkOB8CbKrERBqGv4-oWaQD9M6uCX8EHk0MMc-JBsWyZtW3Z2G0U51YLiH/favicon.ico?psid=1) sem aviso. Cheguei a lembrar de verificar as imagens mas me esqueci do favicon.

## Contexto

Conforme as referências da pergunta, muitas pessoas estão obtendo esse erro.
No meu caso não era questão de configuração de metadata, JavaScript SDK ou nada do gênero.

O Facebook está encontrando algum erro ao fazer o parse do conteúdo das URLs compartilhadas. Não há nenhum indicativo de qual seria o erro, muito menos o motivo dele ocorrer. O que sabemos é que o `sharer.php` retorna uma página vazia com código 500.

Fiz alguns [testes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19900/discussion-on-question-by-anthony-accioly-compartilhar-artigo-no-facebook-popu) clonando o *markup* do meu blog para outro endereço. Obtive o mesmo resultado do endereço original (erro 500 / pop-up em branco).

Por sugestão do usuário [@Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) tentei então criar uma página com *markup* mínimo nesse endereço. O compartilhamento funcionou sem problemas.

Infelizmente quando tentei copiar esse mesmo *markup* mínimo para uma URL já existente o `sharer` não funcionou. Nesse momento duas coisas ficaram aparentes:

1. Alguma coisa no *markup* da minha página estava quebrando o `sharer`. Provavelmente o *crawler* do Facebook estava se perdendo ou recebendo uma exceção interna (*timeout* ou algo do gênero).
2. O Facebook mantém um *cache* das informações da URL. Enquanto esse *cache* não for invalidado não é possível compartilhar a página.

## Ações Tomadas

1. Passei alguns dias tentando isolar os trechos de *markup* da minha página que seriam responsáveis pelo problema. Não consegui isolá-los (porém mantive um [*mock* com o layout anterior](http://accioly2.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/post-de-teste-para-compartilhamento.html) da página caso alguém se interesse pelo desafio).
2. Finalmente resolvi "apelar". Descartei todo o meu layout e comecei do zero, no processo me livrei de imagens mais pesadas e tudo que não era mais necessário (incluindo metadados do Facebook, imagem do background, vários scripts, etc). Percebi que novos *posts* conseguiam ser compartilhados; porém os posts antigos infelizmente continuavam não funcionando.
3. Finalmente abri o [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) do *Scraper* do Facebook. Para cada URL que não funcionava cliquei no botão *Fetch New Scrape Information*. As novas informações foram então devidamente encontradas e o `sharer` voltou a funcionar.

Para arrumar problemas como esse, a melhor ferramenta que encontrei foi o [Debugger do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). Com ele você pode extrair novas informações com o *Scraper* proprietário deles até que os erros sejam resolvidos.

### Exemplo de página com erro

- **URL**: http://accioly2.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/mooc-principios-de-programacao.html
- **Debugger**: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Faccioly2.blogspot.com.br%2F2014%2F12%2Fmooc-principios-de-programacao.html
- **Resultado**: [image: Erro]

### Exemplo de página sem erro

- **URL**: http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2013/09/mooc-principios-de-programacao.html
- **Debugger**: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fa.accioly.7rtc.com%2F2013%2F09%2Fmooc-principios-de-programacao.html
- **Resultado**: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Confesso que cheguei a pesquisar sobre esse problema e fiz alguns teste no seu blog, mas não deu em nada. Com essa solução só consigo pensar que é um problema de *cache* interno do próprio Facebook. Seria interessante submeter um *bug report* para eles ficarem a par disso, não?

Comment: Criei um [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/579081972235647/). Vamos ver se chama a atenção... Não tenho grandes expectativas, mas vai que eles me surpreendem.

Comment: No final o bandido era o [favicon](http://s0z0tg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pOvhcR2DWzPHr171Z6EU1__JIjRYOT-LnciCsvCgOkOB8CbKrERBqGv4-oWaQD9M6uCX8EHk0MMc-JBsWyZtW3Z2G0U51YLiH/favicon.ico) hospedado nos servidores da Microsoft One Drive... Eu cheguei a verificar e mudar algumas imagens, mas não pensei no favicon. :(

Comment: Faz tempo que não via esta questão, nossa um favicon, isto realmente pode ser uma boa dica. Fico feliz que encontrou o problema. Seria interessante se `sharer.php` apresenta-se uma mensagem de erro mínimo junto a resposta `500`. Mas com certeza o debugger foi uma grande e útil ferramenta, obrigado por compartilhar. +1