# Meta author não incorpora ao compartilhar no Facebook

Tags: wordpress

Quando eu compartilho um link do meu site em uma página do Facebook, o "by AUTOR" não está aparecendo. Eu já informei todas as redes sociais corretas dentro do perfil do meu usuário.
Estou usando o plugin YOAST. Como tenho outros sites em que isso está funcionando, pois deixei as mesmas opções iguais. Não sei o que pode ser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Update:
Está aparecendo um erro no Object Debugger.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Update 2: Está funcionando, porém há esses dois erros.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código fonte da URL que tentei compartilhar http://pastebin.com/t0pB4qFy

Comment: Poste a estrutura HTML das meta tags geradas.

Comment: Pode estar relacionado com o cache do facebook. Consulte essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115902/4793

Comment: Como disse o @GuilhermeNascimento, seria conveniente que você postasse a estrutura das tags.
Talvez esse artigo possa ajudar: http://tableless.com.br/utilizando-meta-tags-facebook/

Comment: @Felipe-stoker eu postei uma resposta que acredito que seja válida, gostaria de saber resolveu seu problema?!

Comment: @CleidimarViana não resolveu ainda.

Comment: @FelipeStoker tentei pesquisar a fundo a questão, e realmente você está esquecendo de fechar alguma aspas ou coisa parecida. Alterei minha resposta colocando um exemplo de comparação do tecmundo. Dê uma olhada e faça uma comparação com suas tags. Se você disponibilizar o link do seu site, posso dar mais uma olhada. Boa Sorte ai! Vlw. Flw

Comment: @CleidimarViana com certeza, o link é www.bettercallsaul.com.br

Comment: @FelipeStoker eh cara, vi que tem alguns metas diferente do Techmundo, no qual citei na minha resposta. Você terá que rever tudo o que você fez até agora, todos os `metas` e tentar corrigir. Fiz o que pude! =) Não consigo mais que isso! Abs. Boa Sorte.

Comment: @CleidimarViana Show de bola, obrigado. Só uma dúvida, o YOAST não inclui as metas automaticamente?

Comment: @FelipeStoker basicamente é isso que tem que fazer, incluindo Facebook Open Graph, Twitter Cards, e Google+ meta data. Se não estiver fazendo, você pode desinstalar e instalar novamente, configurando do zero, por desencargo de consciência.

Comment: Aperte Ctrl+U na página copie o source HTML gerado e cole na pergunta (se for muito grande cole no http://pastebin.com e coloque o link na pergunta), assim teremos uma noção do que esta quebrando teu HTML, é bem provavel que seja algum outro plugin ou algo que você, até então não temos como descobrir.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei a pergunta com o código-fonte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que foi injetado o código do facebook antes do doctype:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=1608515189361899";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Ou seja é provavel que você tenha inserido manualmente, para corrigir, terá que pegar esta parte e adicionar dentro de BODY de alguma forma:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=1608515189361899";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Vou instalar o Wordpress e depois dou uma sugestão

Comment: Ahh entendi, será que posso colocar esse código antes do fechamento do </body>?

Comment: @FelipeStoker sim, perfeito, é o lugar mais apropriado.

Comment: você sabe onde geralmente fica o fechamento do Body? pois no header.php não é.

Comment: @FelipeStoker seria no `footer.php`? Mas eu acho que tem que adicionar pelo tema: Appearance -> Editor -> Nome do tema atual

Comment: Quase lá cara, está funcionando, mas há dois erros no debugger, sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @FelipeStoker poderia mandar os erros para eu ler?

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar. Eu coloquei o erro no update 2 da minha pergunta.

Comment: @FelipeStoker você adicionou a meta-tag de url duas vezes, as meta-tags do tipo article só pode ter uma `og:url`

Comment: Sabe o que pode ter ocasionado isso? Pois fiz tudo pelo YOAST.

Comment: @FelipeStoker instalei aqui e funciona normalmente, você deve ter algum plugin adicional que esta afetando, quando se trata de SEO é melhor só usar um plugin do tipo, usar mais de um pode dar problemas.

Comment: Que estranho, o outro que tenho é o Shareaholic | share buttons, analytics, related content, mas esse é apenas para compartilhar o conteúdo da página. Será que é ele?

Comment: @FelipeStoker desativa todos e vai ativando com Ctrl+U e F5 até descobrir qual é

Comment: Já descobri, era algo do próprio tema.

Answer (score 5):

Olá, a metatag que o Facebook utiliza para obter o autor que publicou a postagem é esta:

```
<meta name=”author” content=”nomedoautor”>
```

Bom, isso dai tem que ser inserido em algum lugar do postagem, para isso eu fiz a seguinte função PHP que deve ser adicionada ao functions.php

Isso pode ser feito no próprio wordpress mesmo, indo em painel de controle → Aparência → Editor

Na lateral você deve selecionar Funções do Tema (functions.php) e no final do arquivo colando o seguinte código:

```
function adiciona_tag_autor_facebook($content) {
    if (is_single()) {
        echo '<meta name="author" content="' . get_the_author() . '"/>';
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'adiciona_tag_autor_facebook');
```

Bom, como o amigo disse acima, a primeira vez que você clica para compartilhar um post no facebook, é gerado um cache, neste caso faça os procedimentos que o Fagner Souza disse e tente compartilhar novamente na sua timeline do facebook. (Os procedimentos dito por ele vai fazer o facebook apagar o cache atual e gerar um novo com as informações atualizadas).

Ou senão, crie uma nova postagem apenas de teste e veja se aparece o nome do autor no card do facebook.

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte.

Comment: Inclui a função, mas não surtiu efeito.

Answer (score 4):

Faça o facebook atualizar seu cache na url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object coloque a url do post e clica em "Fetch new..."

Comment: Fiz isso e apareceu um erro http://prntscr.com/c8ncp3

Comment: @FelipeStoker verifica as tuas tags, a ver se estão direitas. As meta-tag também. Deve ser um problema de estrutura HTML

Comment: Oi Felipe, tem como revisar o template do WordPress e garantir que as tags estão dentro do `header`? O Facebook é cheio de "particularidades", por exemplo, veja [a minha saga devido a um favicon bloqueado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43306/compartilhar-artigo-no-facebook-popup-janela-em-branco).

Comment: Já havia feito isso, mas continua igual.

Answer (score 1):

## Com plugin Yoast WordPress SEO

Com o plugin [Yoast WordPress SEO](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-seo-plugin-by-yoast/), você precisa entra em SEO » Page social na administração do WordPress e verificar se caixa ao lado "Add Open Graph meta data" está marcada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O próximo passo é adicionar o seu ID do Facebook em sua conta WordPress. Basta visitar Users » Your Profile e inserir a URL do seu perfil do Facebook e clique no botão Salvar para armazenar as configurações como mostra abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Sem plugin Yoast

Se você quiser adicionar meta tag 'autor' em seu site sem um plug-in,  basta adicionar o seguinte código no do seu site `<head>`.

```html
<meta property="article:publisher" content="http://facebook.com/seuperfil" />
<meta property="article:author" content="http://facebook.com/seuperfil" />
```

Dê uma lida neste links:

- [Sharing Best Practices for Websites & Mobile Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)
- [Social media otimization with Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/social-media-optimization-with-wordpress-seo-by-yoast/)

#### Quanto a imagem do erro

Na sua devida tradução:

> Sua página possui meta tags no `body` em vez da `head`. Isso pode ser
>   porque o `HTML` está mal formado e eles caíram mais baixo na árvore de
>   análise. Por favor corrigir isso para que as tags para ser utilizável.

Tente formatar o seu código usando este site: https://www.dirtymarkup.com/ . Talvez tenha alguma aspas fechando em lugar indevido.

## Observação

Verifiquei os `metas` do site do [Techmundo](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/) no [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) e nos [resultados](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tecmundo.com.br%2F) retornou estes três valores abaixo referente ao facebook:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="111090485635468" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="247082808662914" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="valdbaixaki" />
```

Tente comparar com os seus resultados e faça as devidas alterações.

Veja a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, no YOAST eu fiz exatamente como você mostrou na imagem. Porém mesmo assim ele continua não mostrando.

Comment: Eu não vou fazer via código, pois o nome de usuário pode variar.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Entendi!

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com um erro aparecendo no debugger do facebook.

Answer (score 0):

O problema parece estar na semântica HTML, conforme exorta a mensagem do facebook:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Corrija colocando as metatags dentro da tag `<head></head>`.

Exemplo:

```
<head>
<meta property="article:author" content="Nome do Autor" />

outras metatags também devem estar aqui.


</head>
```

Após isso, atualize o cache no debugger do facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object

Verifique se não possui outros erros de semântica, pois o facebook pode ainda recusar caso encontre outro erro.

Para verificar a validade do HTML: https://validator.w3.org/

E não se esqueça de sempre atualizar o cache na página de debug do facebook.