# Meta Author não incorpora no site

Tags: facebook

Sempre que compartilho um post do meu site em minha página do Facebook, aparece o nome do autor do lado da notícia. Porém, essa semana, parou de aparecer.
Eu estava pesquisando e vi que é problema com *meta author*. Eu já havia feito uma pergunta referente à esse mesmo problema antigamente [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147247/meta-author-n%C3%A3o-incorpora-ao-compartilhar-no-facebook). Segui os passos que foram informado nesse post, mas não resolveu.
Alguém sabe o que pode ter acontecido?

Link da notícia:
http://strangerthings.com.br/noticias/sbt-ira-exibir-uma-hora-de-stranger-things-em-sua-programacao/

Inclui o código do Facebook na Header:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'ID',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para podermos te ajudar, [forneça um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza alterei a pergunta

Comment: Você já tentou colocar o `Script` no final da página ?

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza tentei e não funcionou

Comment: Tente também colocar a tag `<meta property='fb:app_id' content='...'>` antes de `<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza estou usando o Yoast SEO.

Comment: Apenas chutando pra tentar ajudar, você já tentou configurar a url que você referencia na tag article:author com HTTPS? Notei no fonte da página que está apontando pra uma url http(url do seu perfil no Facebook). Talvez não tenha nenhuma relação, mas não custa verificar.

Comment: Já tentou  alterar a opção no seu perfil do Facebook em "Configs > Publicações Públicas" para "Público"?

Comment: @DvD mas isso acontece com outros admins. Sendo que isso estava funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Conhece algum site onde isso esteja funcionando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Facebook parou de mostrar a Meta Author, somente estão sendo exibidos os sites que ficaram em cache. Aparentemente eles estão reformulando o modo com que os compartilhamentos estão aparecendo (essa mudança vem sendo implementada desde o começo deste ano [Link Noticia sobre parte da mudança](https://noticias.uol.com.br/confere/ultimas-noticias/2017/04/28/facebook-mudou-a-forma-de-compartilhar-suas-publicacoes-entenda-o-que-houve.htm)), veja na API deles o debugger de compartilhamento do seu SITE, a Meta Author é reconhecida, é exibida, mas não é mais colocada no compartilhamento:

[Link API Dubugger Compartilhamento](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstrangerthings.com.br%2Fnoticias%2Fsbt-ira-exibir-uma-hora-de-stranger-things-em-sua-programacao%2F)

Isso não está ocorrendo apenas com seu site fique tranquilo, vamos esperar um posicionamento Official sobre as mudanças no modo de compartilhamento para obtermos mais informações.

Answer (score 2):

Uso no meu app, o mesmo endereco para o publisher e author, no qual o seu seria https://www.facebook.com/strangerthings.com.br, e seu publisher tem um slash a mais.

```
 <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/strangerthings.com.br/" />
    <meta property="article:author" content="http://www.facebook.com/felipestoker" />
```

Comment: Como eu tiro isso?

Comment: voce nao precisa tirar e sim corrigir, se a publicacao vem da sua pagina, deve colocar somente o link da pagina e vice versa

Comment: Eu estou usando o plugin YOAST do Wordpress.

Comment: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/facebook-publisher-tags/

Comment: Já está com a URL correta e o Open Graph ok.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei na documentação, você já tentou?

**Ativar etiquetas de Author do Facebook**

Para o recurso de marcas do autor do Facebook funcionar, você precisa entrar na página de perfil do usuário da sua instalação do WordPress e inserir seu próprio URL de perfil do Facebook. É isso aí. O plugin irá adicionar automaticamente mais coisas, como tags do editor, tags de imagem, uma etiqueta de descrição, tipo de artigo etc. etc.

Se você quiser otimizar ainda mais sua saída OpenGraph, você pode alterar algumas das coisas que o plugin exibe na guia social do WordPress SEO.

> https://yoast.com/facebook-author-tags/

Comment: Isso já está ativado.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que os autores precisam dar permissão para uma publicação ou site (e, especificamente, a página FB desse site) para serem citados como autor.

Os autores precisam fazer login no seu próprio perfil do Facebook, ir em Configurações e, em seguida, clicar em "Publicações Vinculadas" (ou acessar https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=author_publisher)

Lá, eles precisam adicionar a página do Facebook da publicação (ou site) como uma "publicação vinculada".

Depois que o autor der a permissão é bom você limpar o cache do Facebook utilizando o [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), basta colocar o link da postagem e clicar em "Scrape Again".

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102093/3102545) também foi sugerido utilizar o `FB_ID` ao invés do alias nas meta tags

Comment: Eu fiz esse processo e nada mudou ainda.

Comment: Quando você entrou em configurações, a página apareceu para selecionar como um publicação vinculada?